# Add an Array to a Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary

I have tried reading the other posts on this subject and can't quite figure this out.

I have a list in C# that I want to put in a dictionary with all of the same keys.  The list is this

```
string[] IN ={"Against","Like","Upon","Through","Of","With","Upon","On","Into","From","by","that","In","About","For"
    ,"Along","Before","Beneath","At","Across","beside","After","Though","Among","Toward","If"};
```

I want to create and populate a dictionary with the key being "IN" (the name of the array) and then having each string for the array in the dictionary.

This is what I wrote to create the dictionary (which I am not sure is correct):

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> wordDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>> ()
```

But I am not sure how to populate the dictionary.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is the first time I have tried to use a dictionary and I am new to C#

Comment: Are you actually trying to add the string array "IN" or are you trying to say that you want to add the name of the variable? Also, this requirement seems like a bad way to structure things... I bet if you give an explanation of what you are attempting to accomplish, we can offer up better solutions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

An array is `string[]`, not `List<string>`, so just do this:

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> wordDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
```

Now you can add your array as usual.

```
wordDictionary.Add("IN", IN);
```

Or:

```
wordDictionary.Add("IN", new string[] {"Against","Like","Upon","Through","Of","With","Upon","On","Into","From","by","that","In","About","For","Along","Before","Beneath","At","Across","beside","After","Though","Among","Toward","If"});
```

Comment: Minitech, This worked great thanks! I guess my question now is how do I access the individual strings in the array that is in the dictionary?

Comment: @miltonjbradley: Like any other array; by index (`wordDictionary["IN"][0] == "Against"`) or by looping (`foreach(string word in wordDictionary["IN"])`) somehow.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dictionary.Add("IN", new List<string>(IN));
```

...if you want to keep the current signature for your dictionary.

If you change it to `Dictionary<string, string[]>` then you can just:

```
Dictionary.Add("IN",IN);
```

Answer (score 1):

You currently have a string *array*, not a list - so it should be:

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> wordDictionary  = new Dictionary<string,string[]> ()
```

Then you can just add items like:

```
wordDictionary.Add("IN" , IN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to convert your array into a string? You could very well use string[] instead of List in your dictionary:

```
var wordDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
wordDictionary.Add("IN", IN);
```

But if you really want to convert your string array to List:

```
var wordDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
wordDictionary.Add("IN", IN.ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to add the array (it's not a list) to the dictionary is to use collection initializer:

```
var wordDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string[]> { "IN", IN };
```

This is *exactly* the same as creating the dictionary in a normal way and then calling `Add("IN", IN)`.