# Load my array into a Dictionary

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary

I have a DataTable. I want to load my DataTable into an Array. Now I want to append my array into my Dictionary using C#. Suggest me some ideas...

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();//I have some column value in my table
 Dictionary<string, object> lst = new Dictionary<string, object>();
var  tableEnumerable = dt.AsEnumerable();
 var  tableArray = tableEnumerable.ToArray();
```

Comment: what fields of table should be included as key and value of dictionary?

Comment: [Add an Array to a Dictionary in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9526626/add-an-array-to-a-dictionary-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Look into it.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487660/how-to-convert-the-value-in-datatable-into-a-string-array-in-c-sharp.

Comment: @monica you can use LINQ ToDictionary to convert array to dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

here is the solution, I think you must search the SO knowledgebase before posting already exist questions.

[How to Convert the value in DataTable into a string array in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487660/how-to-convert-the-value-in-datatable-into-a-string-array-in-c-sharp)